# Name for a pair of vertices connected by an edge

Tags: graph-theory

What is the proper name for a pair of vertices connected by an edge?

NOTE: Lots of googling didn't yield an answer.

DISCLAIMER: I am no math expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adjacent vertices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacentVertices.html)

Comment: isn't there a more concise definition?

Comment: I thought you were looking for the term which fits the definition you provided. If you want a more concise term then you can use it in the following manner "Vertices A & B are adjacent".

Comment: @jldupont: are you looking for a _term_ or a _definition_? Besides "adjacent vertices" I can only think of "neighboring vertices" as far as terms. These are already relatively short terms. I suppose if you really wanted to, you could define a shorter term yourself, but I don't really see the point of this.

Comment: Sorry: I meant as per question i.e. a concise name.